# Saving, Loading, Deleting from textarea to LocalStorage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have managed to be able to get the textarea to save using JavaScript but cannot seem to delete or load it back into the textarea.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Cool, cool... so what have you tried so far? SO is not here to do your work for you, we're here to help *you* with *your* code, so: show code? And [include some more details](/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

Code for saving:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

Code for loading back:

```
document.getElementById("myTextareaId").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Maybe I could help more if you gave me a little bit more information and code.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a text area from localStorage:

```
document.getElementById("text-area").value = localStorage.getItem("savedContent");
```

To remove an item from localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem("savedContent");
```